# Java: How to check if first character typed == x

Tags: java, if-statement, character

I have a textview and 3 button with `textview.append("1");` `textview.append("2");` `textview.append("3");` command,
and another button, button4, with empty command.

My question is how can I check if the first character typed in textview is 1 when button4 pressed?

For example:

```
public void button4 (View v)
{   
    if (first character in textview == 1)
    {
        textview.setText("xxx");
    }
    else if (first character in textview == 2)
    {
        textview.setText("yyy");
    }
    else 
    {
        texteview.setText("zzz");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this will work:

```
textview.getText().charAt(0)
```

Comment: Yes this is work, but only work with number ex: 
if (textview.getText().charAt(0) == 1){}


how to use a string?

like:
if (textview.getText().charAt(0) == a){}

Comment: Oh you need to check against the String 'a', not the variable a.

So `textview.getText().charAt(0)=='a'` is what you want.

Comment: Still not working, only working with number (Integer etc) data type

Comment: Ok what happens if you do `char c = textview.getText().charAt(0)` then test `c` against a character?  From what you've said, somehow you seem to be getting an `int` from the first index of a `String`, and that's just weird.